# React-native android: not visible image use react-native-image-progress

Tags: react-native

I have a problem: not visible image when I use react-native-image-progress, react-native-fast-image.
   I want to add loading image for listview. Thanks!!!

```
import ProgressBar from 'react-native-progress/CircleSnail';
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image';
import { createImageProgress } from 'react-native-image-progress';
const Image = createImageProgress(FastImage);
    <TouchableNativeFeedback
        background={TouchableNativeFeedback.SelectableBackground()}
    >
        <Image
              source={{ uri: 'url' }}
              style={styles.Image}
              indicator={ProgressBar}
          />
   </TouchableNativeFeedback>
```

[image: error Image]

Comment: Is `url` https?

Comment: Yes. this is a link.

Comment: I mean is it https and not http.

Comment: Yes, It is https.

Answer (score 0):

You can `fetch` images before showing them. You don't have to use a library for this.

**Example**

```
fetch(url).then(()=> { this.setState({ loading: false }) });

<Image source={this.state.loading === true ? require('/path/to/loading.gif') : { uri: url }} />
```

Comment: Thanks for help. but I'am new member, :(( .Can you explain better? Where is the line of code located? (fetch(url).then(()=> { this.setState({ loading: false }) });
)

Comment: You can read more about `fetch` [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#using-fetch) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Basically you are downloading the image so it caches while you are showing the loading then when you change it it directly reads from cache and shows it instantly.

Comment: url is this.props.url. I don't know fetch url.

Comment: Please refer to the documentation of `fetch`. url is the image url.